# Mongoose schema transform field before returning the record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is it possible to add a default value if the field is empty/not present in the record?

ex:

```
if ( ! record.options ) { record.options = {}; }
```

After searching a lot, the response i found was i can do this using `.toObject()` or `.toJSON()`, But i am not calling any of these and i just want to add this conditions on the schema so it works directly.

Right now i am checking for this condition in the returned record/(s) which is bad as i am repeating the same logic for `.find` and `.findOne`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add empty default value, you need to do something like this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
   info: { type: <YOUR_TYPE_HERE>, default: {} }
 }, { minimize: false });
```